# Laravel Elixir rev.manifest.json file not being updated

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, laravel-5.3, laravel-elixir

I am currently using Laravel 5.3 and I have encountered an issue with versioning

Here is my code

```
mix.version('fonts/');
mix.version('css/');
mix.version('js/');
```

I can see all the files being generated with the hash in the `build` directory. But however, the `rev-manifest.json` file is not being updated accordingly. And I get no errors or whatsoever when I run `gulp`

I can see only the css in my `rev-manifest.json` file

```
{
  "css/default-dark.css": "css/default-dark-bed08371c4.css",
  "css/default-dark.css.map": "css/default-dark-2a4c6cb94a.css.map",
  "css/lib.css": "css/lib-384fba1ad2.css",
  "css/lib.css.map": "css/lib-a51e31f73b.css.map",
  "css/main.css": "css/main-cfc4bd83eb.css",
  "css/main.css.map": "css/main-d92395245d.css.map",
  "css/select2-spinner.gif": "css/select2-spinner-7b9776076d.gif",
  "css/select2.png": "css/select2-2ca61b76e2.png",
  "css/select22x2.png": "css/select22x2-49e3f00601.png",
  "css/spinners.css": "css/spinners-3d9b0b648c.css"
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?